# Change title in redhat, bash

Tags: python, bash, putty

How do I change the "putty" title in python?

It works when python is enabled:

```
# python
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout.write("\x1b]2;Another Title\x07")
```

The following does NOT WORK:

in py:

```
# ./myscript
```

myscript:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
sys.stdout.write("\x1b]2;Another Title\x07")
```

echo

```
# echo "\x1b]2;Another Title\x07"
\x1b]2;Another Title\x07
```

echo -e

```
# echo -e "\x1b]2;Another Title\x07"
```

print

```
# print
-bash: print: command not found
```

Comment: If you are referring to the hex codes not being expanded, i think this is because bash expands oct codes by default, try `\007`. Also can you explain how it doesnt work ?

Comment: Great! ;)
echo -e "\027Another Title\007"

Answer (score 1):

Jidder Thanks,

Solution:
 echo -e "\027Another Title\007"

Answer (score -1):

http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.63/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-title:

> `PuTTY` allows the server to send `xterm` control sequences which modify the title of the window in mid-session.

http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/text/Xterm-Title:

> 3.1.  `xterm` escape sequences
>
> Window and icon titles may be changed in a running `xterm` by using
>    `XTerm` escape sequences. The following sequences are useful in this
>    respect:
>
> - `ESC]0;stringBEL` -- Set icon name and window title to string
> - `ESC]1;stringBEL` -- Set icon name to string
> - `ESC]2;stringBEL` -- Set window title to string
>
>   where `ESC` is the escape character (`\033`), and `BEL` is the bell
>     character (`\007`).

Which means what you want is:

```
$ printf "\033]0;My shiny new title\007"
```

PS: Don't use `echo` with options (`-n`/`-e`, it's not portable).

Comment: @flig Works perfectly fine for me in accordance with the manual, both directly in a bash shell as well as using `sys.stdout.write` in a `python` shell.